# Wordpress search with meta_query not returning results

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom query that runs for job searches. If I remove the `meta_query` I get al jobs that match my `$search_term` value. I checked to ensure the published job has the correct `key` and `value` as a custom field. However, no jobs are returned.

```
array( 
        'post_type' => 'job',
        's' => $search_term,
        'order' => 'DSC',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
        'paged' => $paged,
        'meta_query' => array(
          array (
            'key' => 'publish_phone_number',
            'value' => 'Yes'
          )
        )
      )
```

This runs through the `WP_QUERY` method.

I'm currently using `meta_query` because I plan on adding other elements, I'm only testing things right now.

If I add this to other queries I get results as expected.

Comment: I think this has to do with how WP handles the `s` argument. You may have to do an array_merge: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78649/using-meta-query-meta-query-with-a-search-query-s

Comment: I think there are two possibilities.
1) If your variables have no data.
2) Also you have not add meta key in wp_query argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try meta query like this

```
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'publish_phone_number',
            'value'     => '',
            'compare'   => '!=',
        ),
    )
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `relation` since there is no other meta query to compare.

Comment: You can modify code accordingly